# Client Side validation in MVC 3 Database First

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

If I add `[Required]` in my entity class then unobtrusive validation works fine.

`[Required]` is not added where I generate my entity class using database first(*.edmx).

If I manually add [Required] in my entity property, something like

```
[Required]
public int {get;set;}
```

`[Required]` will delete when I update my edmx.

So my question is how can I perform client side validation if I use database first in EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a partial class for your entity and use the *MetadataType* attribute. See example below:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyEntity.Metadata))]
public partial class MyEntity
{
    private sealed class Metadata
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* required")]
        public string MyRequiredField { get; set; }
    }

    // Add other similar properties here...
}
```

This class will be unaffected by changes in the designer generated code.

Comment: to make it clear, here MyEntity is the Database first Generated Class, [this](http://www.elevenwinds.com/data-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-database-first) too helped me

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for ado.net team. I suppose  that when you use database first EF your domain model inherits constraints of database because database design is master for your application logic.